# Dealloc method in iOS and setting objects to nil

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, dealloc

I have a pretty basic question. In some examples I've seen, objects are just released in the dealloc method. In others, the objects are released and then set to `nil`. Is there a reason for this? Is setting to nil after releasing advantageous?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Three ways to dealloc

**1. Just release**

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [airplane release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Now the object reference points to a random position, which may be one of two things:

1. Most likely it is garbage, because the memory position can't be interpreted as an object.
2. Rarely it will be a different object, because memory have been reused to create a new object.

The effect of a further method calls through this pointer is one of these three (which one is undefined):

- A crash with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` because the pointer points to garbage.
- A crash with *undefined selector* because it points to a valid object which doesn't have that method.
- A successful method execution because the new object has a method by the same name.

**2. Release and nil**

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [airplane release], airplane = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Now the object reference is nil and any further method calls are ignored. This may silently cause a defined but unforeseen lateral effect in your code, but at least it doesn't crash your application.

**3. Nil and release**

```
- (void)dealloc {
    id temp = airplane;
    airplane = nil;
    [temp release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

This is the same as before, but it removes that small window between release and nil where the object reference points to an invalid object.

### Which one is best?

It is a matter of choice:

- If you rather crash choose just release.
- If you rather ignore the mistake choose nil+release or release+nil.
- If you are using `NSZombieEnabled=TRUE` then just release, don't nil the zombie!

### Macros and zombies

A easy way to defer your choice is using a macro. Instead `[airplane release]` you write `safeRelease(x)` where safeRelease is the following macro that you add to your .pch target file:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
  #define safeRelease(x) [x release]
#else
  #define safeRelease(x) [x release], x=nil
#endif
```

This macro doesn't respect zombies. Here is the problem: when `NSZombieEnabled` is `TRUE` the object turns into a `NSZombie`. If you nil its object reference, any call sent to him will be ignored.

To fix that, here is a macro from [Kevin Ballard](http://blog.eridi.us/) that sets the pointer to an invalid made up reference ONLY when `NSZombieEnabled` is `FALSE`. This guarantees a crash during debug time if zombies are not enabled, but leaves the zombies be otherwise.

```
#if DEBUG
  #define safeRelease(x) do { [x release]; if (!getenv("NSZombieEnabled")) x = (id)0xDEADBEEF; } while (0)
#else
  #define safeRelease(x) [x release], x = nil
#endif
```

### References

Apple doesn't have a recommendation on which one is best. If you want to read the thoughts of the community here are some links (the comment threads are great too):

- [Dealloc](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/09/dealloc.html) Jeff Lamarche
- [Don’t Coddle Your Code](http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/1423/dont-coddle-your-code) Daniel Jalkut
- [More on dealloc](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/09/more-on-dealloc.html) Jeff Lamarche
- [To nil, or not to nil, that is the question](http://digdog.tumblr.com/post/1177480301/to-nil-or-not-to-nil-that-is-the-question) Ching-Lan Huang
- [Defensive Coding in Objective-C](http://zathras.de/blog-defensive-coding-in-objective-c.htm) Uli Kusterer

Comment: This was a great answer. Thank you!

Comment: "in which case your app crashes" in WHAT case your app crashes? "Your call crashes" WHAT call? I don't see anyone asking about any call

Comment: I was referring (in my head) to method calls on the released pointer. I edited for clarification.

Comment: Recommended you use arc in ios7.  you can't call dealloc

Comment: In an implementation of dealloc, do not invoke the superclass’s implementation. https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1571947-dealloc

Comment: @MacMark this post was written before ARC. In ARC the call to super is automatic, it is a compiler error to call `super dealloc` manually.

Answer (score 3):

This snippet **covers all the bases** and is **ready to cut and paste** into a `.pch` file.

```
// SAFE_RELEASE
//      Releases an object, then does other things based on context.
//
//      The intention is to fail early during internal testing but prevent
//          customers from experiencing crashes if at all possible.
//
// For more information see:
//      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778793/dealloc-method-in-ios-and-setting-objects-to-nil
//
// Debug build:
//      If zombies are enabled, the macro just calls |release|. The zombie
//          mechanism will continue to be used to find messages sent to
//          the deallocated object.
//      Otherwise, zombies are not enabled, so the macro sets the object to a
//          invalid memory address. (0xDEADBEEF.) This will intentionally
//          cause a crash if the object is used, allowing the bug to be found
//          and fixed immediately.
//
// Release build:
//      The macro calls |release| normally. Then it sets the object to nil to
//          prevent a possible crash caused by sending a message to a
//          deallocated object. Messages sent to nil are always allowed.
//
#if DEBUG
#define SAFE_RELEASE(x) \
    do { \
        [x release]; \
        if (!getenv("NSZombieEnabled")) \
            x = (id)0xDEADBEEF; \
    } while (0)
#else
#define SAFE_RELEASE(x) \
    [x release], x = nil
#endif
```

The code is functionally equivalent to Jano's second version of `safeRelease`, but adds documentation and compliance with [Google's coding standards](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml).

Answer (score 1):

If there's a `dealloc` call in more than one place, setting the object variable to nil makes sure it won't be deallocated more than once by mistake. Same logic if the function with the `dealloc` is called from more than one place, or can be called arbitrarily by external code (i. e. other classes).

In real life, this typically happens when the enclosing object is "reusable" - supports multiple rounds of content initialization/teardown. The `nil`-ness of object pointers then becomes a valuable component of object state - it means that the object is "empty" right now.

Sorry for the generalities.

Comment: "If there's a dealloc call in more than one place" What does "dealloc call in more than one place" mean? You are not supposed to call `dealloc`

Comment: When this answer was written, you were supposed to :) Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) was not always around.

Comment: No, you were NEVER supposed to call `dealloc` yourself, except for `[super dealloc]`

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)dealloc
{
     [searchPlace release];
     [super dealloc];
}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
     [super viewDidUnload];
     self.searchPlace = nil;
}
```

Is this like what you say?