# What is the difference between setting object = nil and [object release] VS [object release] and object = nil?

Tags: objective-c, ios, release

What is the difference between these two code snippets:

```
object = nil;
[object release]
```

Vs

```
[object release];
object = nil;
```

which is the best practice ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778793/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
object = nil; 
[object release]
```

**Don't do that.** You are sending a `release` message on a nil object that will just do nothing. But the object that was referenced by your object is still in memory because it has never received a `release` message.

```
[object release]; 
object = nil;
```

Here you release the object, and for convenience and security, you set `nil` to its reference. So you can call (by mistake of course :-) ) any method on that object and the app won't crash.

But if you use a retained property `@property(nonatomic, retain)`, calling :

```
self.object = nil;
```

equals to call :

```
[object release]; 
object = nil;
```

Comment: Hi @Oliver, is that equal for `[object release];` & `[object release];object = nil;` when 'you use a retained property @property(nonatomic, retain)'?

Comment: @Kjuly:No, if you just release it, it is not set to nil. If you set it just to nil, it is released and set to nil. If you release it and set it to nil, it's the same that just setting it to nil. For a retained property of course.

Comment: @Oliver In the last part, you said that setting nil to retain property is equal to release + nil. Can you link to the document ?

Comment: @entropy : some searches on the net will help you finding the docv. The point is that when you set a retained property to nil, you remove the link to the "old" object so it is not retained anymore and is released (this is how the retained properties works). And the new value of the property becomes the one you put, so it's nil.